# Trying to refer to body in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, firebug, jsfiddle, document-body

I've always had some issues with JSFiddle and I'm not sure why, but I figure I should get them sorted out.

For one, I can't figure out how to reference the `body` element from JS Fiddle. Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

It might be a little hard to see, but Firebug is giving a ReferenceError, saying that `body` is not defined. Nothing is printed in the result area.

Here's a live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V4Mg6/.

**EDIT**: I'm an idiot. Thanks, guys.

Comment: your firebug is in the wrong frame...

Comment: you're inspecting the top frame. and also, it's document.body, not just body, unless body has an id of body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.body`, not just `body`.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I missed that. I could've sworn I've just used `body` in the past, but I must have been dreaming. Thanks.

Comment: I think I'm going to delete this question, since it's not useful to anyone and has nothing to do with JSFiddle. Thank you for your effort though. EDIT: Can't delete it now, never mind. I'll vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

It's `document.body` not just `body`